# Fetch multiple properties from an array of objects and form a new one : Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Been trying to do the following thing:

I have an array of objects ,

```
var arr = [
  { key: "aabFaa", text: "aabFaa" ,field: "firstName",checked: true},
  { key: "aAaaaa", text: "aAaaaa", field: "firstName", checked: true },
];
```

Would want to fetch the "text" and "field" out of it and form a new array of objects something like this:

```
result = [ { "field" : "firstName" , value : "aabFaa" , type :"add"}, 
           { "field" : "firstName" , value : "aAaaaa" , type: "add"}
         ]
```

Here type is hard coded one, where as rest are fetched from the "arr"

Whats the easier way to do this?

Have tried this:

```js
var arr = [
  { key: "aabFaa", text: "aabFaa" ,field: "firstName",checked: true},
  { key: "aAaaaa", text: "aAaaaa", field: "firstName", checked: true },
];

let result = arr.map(a => a.text); 
console.log(result)
```

But this has to be written in multiple lines to get desired properties.Is there an easier approach?

Comment: Curious as to what you mean by "easier way" - what's easier than mapping over each item and returning the object with properties you need? "has to be written in multiple lines" Do you really need a one-liner for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `map` with `Object Destructuring`.

```js
var arr = [
    { key: "aabFaa", text: "aabFaa" ,field: "firstName",checked: true},
    { key: "aAaaaa", text: "aAaaaa", field: "firstName", checked: true },
  ];

const output = arr.map(({field, text}) => ({field, value: text, type: "add"}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map seems like a good approach, but you would return a new object and not just one property:

```js
let result = arr.map(a => ({value: a.text, type: 'add', field: a.field}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = arr.map(obj => ({
    field: obj.field,
    value: obj.text,
    type: "add"
}));
```